# Why is my program going into both an if statement AND its corresponding else statement?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, if-statement

In part of my program, I have the code:

```
    if(cameraName == L"AVT Prosilica GT2750") {
        mCamera = new camera_avtcam_ex_t();
    } else if(cameraName == L"QImaging Retiga 2000R\\4000R") {
        mCamera = new camera_qcam_ex_t();
    }
```

When I have set up my program so that cameraName defaults to L"AVT Prosilica GT2750" (and my debugger will show this to be its value), it goes into the if statement and runs `mCamera = new camera_avtcam_ex_t();`, but then when I step to the next executed line my debugger skips directly to the line `mCamera = new camera_qcam_ex_t();` and executes it.  How can this possibly be happening given the nature of if/else statements?

NOTE:  If I replace the else if with just a simple else statement, the same behavior is seen.

Comment: Are you debugging a release build?

Comment: Failed recompile is the first thing that comes to my mind.

Comment: Stray semicolon, perhaps?

Comment: @pstrjds Yes, but to be honest I haven't run into an issue when debugging a release build yet so I'm not familiar with the differences between debugging in debug vs release modes.

Comment: That is the reason you are seeing this than.  Try debugging a "debug" build. You should see the behavior you are expecting. When debugging an optimized build the lines don't necessarily 'line up' with the source code. For all you know, the optimizer decided that it was best to execute both of those and throw one away if it wasn't needed.

Comment: @pstrjds - I suggest you post this as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing this due to trying to debug a release build

Try debugging a "debug" build. You should see the behavior you are expecting. When debugging an optimized build the lines don't necessarily 'line up' with the source code. For all you know, the optimizer decided that it was best to execute both of those and throw one away if it wasn't needed.

Note - I am not suggesting the optimizer did do that, I am just saying it is possible and that you may actually be seeing what line is being executed next.  The optimizer is free to reorder the code, unroll loops, propogate constants, remove variables add temporaries, etc, etc, etc.

Edit - additional thoughts
When you get down to the hardware level things can get really reordered. The hardware may choose to execute both sides of a branch before it figures out which one should be taken so that the answer is ready as soon as it is needed. It will do that even though it means throwing other work away as that may yield faster execution.

Comment: I can't believe it's true that any compiler or hardware would execute the code in both of those blocks before evaluating the `if` condition.  `camera_qcam_ex_t` could have side effects, and the language guarantees it will not be run "just in case".  Your first statement may still be correct, though, that the debugger is just pointing at the wrong line of code.

Comment: It's also possible that the two constructors are very similar, and the compiler decided to share some common code. To find out for sure, drop to the assembly language and see what it's doing.

Comment: @NateHekman - I was just saying that it could - I don't think it would, but the optimizer can do crazy things.  Or as Raymond pointed out, they are similar and so it pulled some common code out.  The idea of code executing that is then thrown away is called "speculative execution" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution